# How to do it the Yii Way

Tags: php, yii

I am having an issue doing the below in Yii way...

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>No of Users</td>
            <td>No of Base Stations</td>
            <td>No of Devices</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo Customer::model()->count();?></td>
            <td><?php echo Basestation::model()->count();?></td>
            <td><?php echo Device::model()->count();?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If there is any way to display it using CActiveDataProvider or any other means. I am new to Yii...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. From my guess you want to count the different models? Your approach is correct just that I would suggest you put that logic in your model/repository so it becomes reusable.

Get the data in your controller and then pass it to your view.